# Can't find how to display generated SQL from Linq

Tags: linq

I have tried to install the linq visualizer debugger, but it doesn't seems to work.

I have tried to find the .Log property and the .GetCommand() methods of the context, but I can't find which of my objects is the context.

```
    public static DATAGESTIONDataSet FillDataSet_Tb_Activite()
    {
        var cn = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ImportSerce.Properties.Settings.DATAGESTIONConnectionString"].ToString());
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Tb_Activite]", cn);
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        var tds = new data.DATAGESTIONDataSet(); // the DATAGESTIONDataSet() is a xsd file, modeled after a MS Access database
        da.Fill(tds, tds.Tb_Activite.TableName);
        cn.Close();
        cn.Dispose();
        return tds;
    }
```

And in the Main() method :

```
        var dsActivites = FillDataSet_Tb_Activite();
        var activitesSoc = from s in dsActivites.Tb_Activite
                               where s.Code.ToLower().StartsWith("w")
                               select s.Ident;
```

On which of my objects should I find the Log property or the GetCommand methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log` is on the `DataContext`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx

You could also run your Linq to Sql code in [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to view the generated SQL.

Or use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to see what SQL is run against your database.

**Update**

However, in this case you are not generating any SQL with Linq. You are using straight `ADO.Net` to fill your dataset. `SELECT * FROM [Tb_Activite]` is returning the entire table, thereafter you are using linq to objects or linq to datasets to query the local in-memory data. That's why you can't find the `DataContext` - you don't have one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is going to help him with his `Dataset`

Comment: @Marc - good point, I didn't read the question properly. I've update my answer.

Comment: +1 -- This is an excellent answer to the problem posed by the poster, even if it does not apply in this case.  I recommend SQL Profiler myself (and would have made it clear to the OP that all his code was doing was selecting a table.)

Comment: Sorry, but it's a really bad answer (to a bad question, granted). I asked what was the DataContext object, and the reply is "use the DataContext". I can't use SQL Profiler, because I'm using MS Access, which I see is not specified in the question, but still. Finally, I tried to use Linqpad, but I couldn't make it work. I will update my question.

Comment: After a bit of thinking, I now realize that my original question is not answerable, so I guess it's the right answer. I will post another question if I have the same problem with my LinqToSql request, further down my project.